# how to log sites visited by user in grails?

Tags: grails, logging, filter

I want to log all sites i mean URL's visited by user in my app to a file.how to do it with log4j.

With advance thank's
Laxmi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [filter](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.6%20Filters):

```
class LogFilters {
   def filters = {
       all(uri: "/**") {
           before = {
               log.info("Controller: ${controllerName}, Action: ${actionName}, Params: ${params}")
           }
       }
   }
```

}

You can log any variable available to the filter. The full list is [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.6.3%20Variables%20and%20Scopes)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can configure your application server to log all requests. In Tomcat for example you can configure an AccessLogValve, as described here. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/valve.html

This way you don't have to redeploy.

Answer (score -1):

you can consider using an [interceptor](http://www.grails.org/Controllers+-+Interceptors) to log each page call

Comment: Wouldn't a filter be better?  The page you link even says they're recommended.